# WPF: Editable ComboBox and StringFormat

Tags: combobox, units-of-measurement, string-formatting

(First of all, I simplified the sample for you to understand.)

I want a **editable** ComboBox that shows values in inches. **The original (source) value is a value in pixels** (DIPs), because this is the unit in which the application works internally. The user shouldn't see the value in pixels, but in inches (the measurement unit of the UI). I determined that I must use a converter to translate from pixels to inches and viceversa.

The ComboBox items should also be formatted with "{0} in".

It should appear like this

```
[ 4 in  |v]
  [ 1 in  ]
  [ 2 in  ]
  [ 3 in  ]
  [ 4 in  ]
```

But, remember, internally it should work in Pixels! and Be Editable. This is the works part. I have been totally unable to achieve this.

I have this so far:

```
  <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
            ItemStringFormat="'{}{0} in}'"                  
            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource MyPixelToInchesConverter}, StringFormat='{}{0} in}'}">
            <system:Double>1</system:Double>
            <system:Double>2</system:Double>
            <system:Double>3</system:Double>
  </ComboBox>
```

The problem? When you select an item, it's not formatted. And when you write a number in the editable region of the ComboBox, it's not formatted, too.

So, what is the best way for a ComboBox to format items even when the user enters a non-existent value??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but I found that setting the `Text` property to use a binding can work, with a bit of a kludge. In my case I was working with a Currency value, but the same principles should apply

```
Text = {Binding Path=Indemnity, StringFormat=C0}
```

However, entering a text value not in the list still exhibits the problem that the `StringFormat` is not applied (for some strange reason known only to the MS folks who designed this).

To work around this, I added a `LostFocus` handler that simply writes an incorrect value, followed by writing the correct value again - at which stage the `StringFormat` is applied:

```
private void IndemnityCombo_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as RatesViewModel;    // A view model class
    if (vm != null) {
        decimal indemnity = vm.Indemnity;
        vm.Indemnity = indemnity + 1M;
        vm.Indemnity = indemnity;
    }
}
```

It's not elegant, but it does the job for me. Hope it can be useful to other users.